# How to retrieve property from GameSparks inside Unity

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties

I am going crazy... I am missing something and I can't see what?!?!

I have created a property called "GAME_SETTINGS" inside the gameSparks admin area and have included this in it:

```
{
    "AppVersionIOS": 1,
    "AppVersionAndroid": 1
}
```

I am then trying to retrieve it inside Unity like this:

```
new GameSparks.Api.Requests.GetPropertyRequest().SetPropertyShortCode("GAME_SETTINGS").Send((response) => {
    if (!response.HasErrors) {
        Debug.Log("Setting Achieved: "+response.JSONString);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Error Getting Settings");
    }
});
```

I can see that I am getting the settings in my Debug.Log:

```
Setting Achieved: {"@class":".GetPropertyResponse","property":{"AppVersionIOS":1,"AppVersionAndroid":1},"requestId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","scriptData":null}
```

My question is though... How do I get the properties AppVersionIOS and AppVersionAndroid inside an Dictionary so I can call on them from other scripts...

Really hoping for help in this matter and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

I actually work for GameSparks and noticed your question so set up an account to answer you. 
The property values returned in the JSON are of nullable type : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Best practice is to parse the values before they are cached in a Dictionary or otherwise.

The following code should allow you to get those properties, then you may store them in a dictionary as you see fit.

```
 public void GetProperties()
{
    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.GetPropertyRequest()
        .SetPropertyShortCode("GAME_SETTINGS")
        .Send((response) =>
        {
            if (!response.HasErrors)
            {
                print(response.JSONString);
                int androidProperty = (int)response.Property.GetInt("AppVersionAndroid");
                int IOSProperty = (int)response.Property.GetInt("AppVersionIOS");
                print("AndroidProperty:" + androidProperty);
                print("IOSProperty:" + IOSProperty);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(response.JSONString);
            }

        });
}
```

Hopefully this solves your problem. If you have any other questions please feel free to head to our website and log a ticket with us. 
Regards, Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice: This answer assumes that the API doesn't have a way of converting this into a nice object which you can easily manipulate / parse, so it converts it itself using some class. It's however very likely that your API offers such a function somewhere, so you'd be better be looking in the documentation again. I guess it's somewhere near https://api.gamesparks.net/#getpropertyrequest .**

You have the JSON document already, all you have to do is parse it. That'd be easier in a JavaScript file than in C#, but you can also use the `JsonUtils` class there, see http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html . Let http://json2csharp.com/ convert that JSON to a class layout for you and you get

```
public class Property
{
    public int AppVersionIOS { get; set; }
    public int AppVersionAndroid { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__@class { get; set; }
    public Property property { get; set; }
    public string requestId { get; set; }
    public object scriptData { get; set; }
}
```

Now just take the string and serialize it into an `RootObject`.

```
new GameSparks.Api.Requests.GetPropertyRequest().SetPropertyShortCode("GAME_SETTINGS").Send((response) => {
    if (!response.HasErrors) {
        Debug.Log("Setting Achieved: "+response.JSONString);
        //Serialization
        var info = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(response.JSONString);

        //Print the AppVersionIOS property
        Debug.Log("App Version iOS: " + info.Property.AppVersionIOS);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Error Getting Settings");
    }
});
```

You might need some mofication in the data types of your class (e.g. make `object scriptData` to `string scriptData` if there can be an actual string in it), but that should be it. Have fun.